# Copy a folder from Docker to host

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-machine

I'm using the following cmd to copy a folder from docker to host.

```
 docker cp nostalgic_brattain:/Documents ~/Documents/MyFolder
```

Unfortunately, it says `Error: No such container:path: nostalgic_brattain:/Documents`

what am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means you are trying to copy for a path inside the container which does not exit. You should exec inside your docker container using `docker exec -it nostalgic_brattain /bin/<shell your container uses (sh or bash)>`
Once inside the container, navigate to the exact location, run the pwd command, and use that in your 'docker cp' command.

You might also be able to find out the location by observing the Dockerfile.

Comment: should I exexute docker cp from a new window?

Comment: i tried  docker cp nostalgic_brattain:/root/Documents/MyFolder ~/Documents but im getting the same error

Comment: @user1241241 Have you identified the exact location of the content you want to copy from inside the container?

Answer (score 1):

In order to copy a file from a container to the host, you can use the command

docker cp :/file/path/within/container /host/path/target

And In order to copy a file/directory from docker to host , use this command in your host
here 167.162.144.169 is my instance id and /mnt/ is the location in my host where I want to copy my file

scp -r root@167.162.144.169:docker-compose /mnt/